# Ubuntu 15.10 - on every single boot strange popup keep showing, is this a bug?

Tags: 15.10, bug-reporting, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and every time i reboot i get this following popup, when i click close it always go back to abnormal resolution which i do not like to use.

[image]

after reboot remain same problem, even after letting it use what itself chooses

Comment: Does this problem also present when using the machine directly? I notice that you are connecting to the machine remotely using VNC Viewer...that could be your problem, if VNC Viewer is trying to force resolutions the hardware is incapable of by default...that could account for the issue.

Comment: Using dual-boot? Try starting system in safe-mode or recovery mode, if it is not dual-boot, try `sudo fdisk -l` (or number your disk).